# Custom data unwrapping in ampersand.js model

Tags: ampersand.js, ampersand-collection

I have a model - `Configuration`:

```
var Configuration = Model.extend({
    props: {
        name: 'string'
    }
});
```

In the database, configuration model / table has 3 columns -> `id`, `name` and `fields`. The latter stores site config as a serialized array. When retrieving the entry from the database, I unserialize it and then pass it to the front end, so the front end receives this:

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": 'global',
    "fields": {
        "enabled": true,
        "site_name": "Test"
    }
};
```

What I want to do is to set whatever is inside `fields` object as `properties` on my model, or maybe `session` so that things get triggered throughout the site when they are updated. To visualize it, I want to achieve something like this:

```
var Configuration = Model.extend({
    props: {
        enabled: 'boolean',
        site_name: 'string'
    }
});
```

So basically, is there are a way to 'unwrap' stuff in `fields` object somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse method is what you're looking for in this case. See https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-state/blob/master/ampersand-state.js#L93-L98 It allows you to transform incoming props.